# Plot Brock value in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to reproduce this plot, called "Brock Value", in R:

[image]

The fromula of the plot (Brock Value) is provided [here](http://brockvalue.com/calculating/).

Being able to pull all the necessary data in R to build this plot would provide most uptodate results which would be very useful, but I am not sure technically how to execute that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where they get data back to 1919, but you can easily get data back to 1950 for all 3 series required to do the calculation using `quantmod::getSymbols`.

The author isn't explicit about which series they used for GDP, so it could be nominal, real, seasonally adjusted, not seasonally adjusted, etc.

```
require(quantmod)

# Pull S&P500 from Yahoo
getSymbols("^GSPC", src="yahoo", from="1947-01-01")
# Convert to monthly, since GDP/AAA are quarterly/monthly, respectively
SPX <- to.monthly(GSPC, name="SPX")

# Pull GDP and AAA bond yield from FRED
getSymbols("AAA;GDP", src="FRED")
# Convert xts index to yearmon, so series will merge cleanly
index(AAA) <- as.yearmon(index(AAA))
index(GDP) <- as.yearmon(index(GDP))

# Merge, fill w/NA, and omit all obs where we don't have data for all 3 series
x <- na.omit(merge(SPX, GDP, AAA, fill=na.locf))
indexTZ(x) <- "UTC"  # avoid potential timezone issues with non-datetime index

# Calculate Brock Value
x$BV <- x$GDP/(2*x$AAA)
# plot
plot(log(x[,c("SPX.Close","BV")]), main="Brock Value")
```

Comment: thank you, nice solution. How would I plot S&P 500 as a background, and Brock value on top of it, like Dr. Brock has above in his example?

Comment: sounds like they used nominal GDP, seasonally adjusted at annual rates.